# How can I secure Firebase with an all client-side implementation?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

I have a very simple Firebase app that is being read and written to via JavaScript all on the client-side. There are no user accounts or server-side applications on my end.

Right now, anyone looking at my JavaScript can copy my Firebase URL and have full read/write access permissions.

Is there any easy way for me to secure this somehow considering I'm doing everything on the client side?

I'm having trouble understanding their documentation and how I can solve this use case.

Comment: Security rules! https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Data access is managed through Firebase's security rules language, that you can find in the Security & Rules tab of your Firebase dashboard.

When you create a new Firebase backend for an app, it defaults to allowing full read/write to everyone.

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

The simplest possible change is to allow everyone to read, but no-one to write:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false
    }
}
```

This way you can only make changes to the data when you're an administrator, i.e. when you're using the Firebase dashboard.

The Firebase documentation has an entire section dedicated to [securing your data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to provide write access to my Javascript client-side application only? I can't seem to find an example for this case.

Comment: Limiting access to code, based on the fact that you authored that code? Nope. That also wouldn't work well in a web environment where everyone can simply copy your code. The common way to secure data is to do user based security.

Comment: If I don't have any users, just an application, would I then have to generate a JWT Token on the server-side using the Firebase Secret, and then pass this token to the client-side application?

Comment: Yup. Or if you don't intend to share this application with anyone, you could embed your Firebase backend's secret in it. But generating a JWT would be safer.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I'll investigate the JWT solution, since this is very new to me.